# Matlab: Read a certain file and make a calculation on columns

Tags: matlab, readfile

I have file names go on 2.txt 4.txt 8.txt 12.txt 14.txt. And each file structure looks like

[image]

I want to read each designated file and do some calculations with the designated columns for instance, after calling 2.txt file I want to calculate
column(A)+column(I)

The questions

1. How can I call the certain file with their name
2. How can I do calculations with this file columns

Here is my code

```
function[t]=ad(x)
    folderName='C:\Users\zeldagrey6\Desktop\AD';
    fileinfo=dir([folderName filesep '**/*.txt'] );
    filename={fileinfo.name};
    fullFileName=[folderName filesep filename{x}];
    d=readtable(fullFileName, 'ReadVariableNames', true);
    t=d.A+d.I;
end
```

The problems of the code

1. When I put ad(2) into array i call 4.txt instead of 2.txt. I guess it does not care the names of the text just read them according to their sequence
2. Is there any way to assign with each column like var1,var2 and do some
   calculations with var1+var2 instead of d.A+d.I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you can refer to table contents with curly brackets like this:

```
A = (30.1:0.1:30.5)';
I = (324:328)';
Angle = (35:5:55)';
FWHM = (0.2:0.05:0.4)';
d = table(A,I,Angle,FWHM);
t1 = d.A + d.I;
t2 = d{:,1} + d{:,2};
```

See that t1 and t2 are equal

Comment: Wow that's great @Yuval Harpaz, thank you so much  t2 = d{:,1} + d{:,2}; worked very well. I kept trying t2 = d(:,1) + d(:,2); with paranthesis and getting error, curly bracket was an answer